# Two graphics in one screen

Tags: android, android-layout, achartengine

I've being trying to display two graphics in one screen but I'm not able. Here is the code where i show one graphic inside the onClick function:

```
case R.id.graphs:
            GraphicalView mChartView = new Niveau().execute(this);
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph);
            layout.removeAllViews();
            layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            break;
```

Any idea??

Thank you very much!

Comment: what problem you are facing  ??? share error log

Comment: With this code I'm not facing any problem but if, for example I try adding this line in order to show two graphics in one screen:

layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

The app closes when I execute it! How do I display more than one graphic in one screen??

Comment: You cannot add twice the same view, you need two different instances with different ids: see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case R.id.graphs:
        GraphicalView mChartView1 = new Niveau().execute(this);
        GraphicalView mChartView2 = //  another chartView creation
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        layout.removeAllViews();
        layout.addView(mChartView1, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(mChartView2, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        break;
```

That should work. Be sure to have different ids on your `mChartView` - if you create them programmatically and not inflated from an XML layout, you need to set the id programmatically too:

```
mChartView1.setId(1);
mChartView2.setId(2);
```

Also, a `RelativeLayout` would probably offer you more customization in term of layout and positionning. You then need to set the relative positions in your layout params:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph);
....
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsForChart2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
paramsForChart2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, mChartView1.getId());
layout.addView(mChartView2, paramsForChart2);
```

Comment: With this, I get no error but I don't see the two graphics in the screen. I just see one! Thx a lot!

Comment: Like this I get two graphics, one on top of the other and I can just make zoom and "play" whith one of them. The other looks static! I'm trying to find a way with the answer you gave me, but if you have more ideas... :-) thx

Comment: Well, I don't know what component you use for your graphic, so it's difficult to say... Make sure you really generate two independent graphics, and they don't share things they shouldn't share :)

Answer (score 1):

Before adding the second layout you have to call `layout.removeAllViews();` so that your Layout is now free to show another layout inside it. So try to remove first and then add the second layout.

Comment: And how do I show two graphics at the same time? Is this possible?Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to show two layout at the same time you need to create to seperate container for both of them. Because at the same time two layout can't be shown over-lapping the other.