# Two graphs displaying on the same screen using AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm trying to add two (or more) graphs into one screen (which has buttons and others elements).

I have been trying to do it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383410/two-graphics-in-one-screen/22105405#22105405) answer to a relative topic as a guide but i have not been able to display the two graphs into one screen using AChartEngine.

I understand that I neew to use GrapihicalView to do it, but i haven´t been able to make it.

Answer (score 0):

I try this:

```
LayoutParams paramsLinear = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(800, 800);
LinearLayout newLinear = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
newLinear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
newLinear.setLayoutParams(paramsLinear);
```

This LinearLayout is a container for my single chart.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure it out like this:

```
protected void onResume()
    {   
        super.onResume();

        if (chart1 == null)
        {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
            chart1 = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset1, multiRenderer1, "HH:mm");
            multiRenderer1.setClickEnabled(true);
            multiRenderer1.setSelectableBuffer(10);

            /**ZOOM on the graph*/
            chart1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    /**handle the click event on the chart*/
                    SeriesSelection seriesSelection = chart1.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                    if (seriesSelection == null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(myActivity.this, "No chart element", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /**display information of the clicked point*/
                        Toast.makeText(
                            myActivity.this,
                            "Closest point value X=" + convertLongToString((long)seriesSelection.getXValue(), "HH:mm") + ", Y=" + seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            layout.addView(chart1, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            boolean enabled = dataset1.getSeriesCount() > 0;
        }
        else
        {
            chart1.repaint();
        }

        if (chart2 == null)
        { 
            LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart2); 
            chart2 = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset2, multiRenderer2, "HH:mm");
            multiRenderer2.setClickEnabled(true);
            multiRenderer2.setSelectableBuffer(10);

            /**ZOOM on the graph*/
            chart2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    /**handle the click event on the chart*/
                    SeriesSelection seriesSelection = chart2.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                    if (seriesSelection == null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(myActivity.this, "No chart element", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /**display information of the clicked point*/
                        Toast.makeText(
                            myActivity.this,
                            "Closest point value X=" + convertLongToString((long)seriesSelection.getXValue(), "HH:mm") + ", Y=" + seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            layout2.addView(chart2, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            boolean enabled = dataset2.getSeriesCount() > 0;
        }
        else
        {
            chart2.repaint();
        }
    }
```